# Do not understand the classes part and reshape from reading a h5 dataset file

Tags: numpy, ipython, h5py

Hello can somebody explain step by step what's hapening in following code?
Escpecially the part classes and the reshape? tnx

```
def load_data():
    train_dataset = h5py.File('datasets/train_catvnoncat.h5', "r")
    train_set_x_orig = np.array(train_dataset["train_set_x"][:]) # your train set features
    train_set_y_orig = np.array(train_dataset["train_set_y"][:]) # your train set labels

    test_dataset = h5py.File('datasets/test_catvnoncat.h5', "r")
    test_set_x_orig = np.array(test_dataset["test_set_x"][:]) # your test set features
    test_set_y_orig = np.array(test_dataset["test_set_y"][:]) # your test set labels

    classes = np.array(test_dataset["list_classes"][:]) # the list of classes

    train_set_y_orig = train_set_y_orig.reshape((1, train_set_y_orig.shape[0]))
    test_set_y_orig = test_set_y_orig.reshape((1, test_set_y_orig.shape[0]))

    return train_set_x_orig, train_set_y_orig, test_set_x_orig, test_set_y_orig, classes
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the lines just load `datasets` from the `h5` file.  The `np.array(...)` wrapper isn't needed.  `test_dataset[name][:]` is sufficient to load an array.

```
test_set_y_orig = test_dataset["test_set_y"][:]
```

`test_dataset` is the opened file.  `test_dataset["test_set_y"]` is a `dataset` on that file.  The `[:]` loads the dataset into a `numpy` array.  Look up the `h5py` docs for more details on load a `dataset`.

I deduce from

```
train_set_y_orig = train_set_y_orig.reshape((1, train_set_y_orig.shape[0]))
```

that the array, as loaded is 1d, with shape `(n,)`, and this reshape is just adding an initial dimension, making it `(1,n)`.  I would have coded it as

```
train_set_y_orig = train_set_y_orig[None,:]
```

but the result is the same.

There's nothing special about the `classes` array (though it might well be an array of strings).